# Screen mirroring of selected area in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, airplay, screen-recording

Is there any way in iPhone through which only a selected area of iPhone screen is mirrored onto TV unlike Airplay's complete screen mirroring?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no "partial" mirroring of your iPhone screen. The AirPlay tap uses the screen recording function which does not allow cropping controls.

You can [use AirPlay to stream video or mirror the screen of your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289).

This functionality is the same on watchOS, iOS and iPadOS as well as macOS, there's no partial mirroring of your display.

The only platform that allows cropping in a screen recording is macOS and that’s due to it being a separate app. If you want to do something like this for the purposes of obfuscating content, you'll need to record the video then redact it manually like blurring or boxing out the portion of the image you want hidden.

If it must be live, consider using [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) that allows you to capture a video stream, modify it then broadcast out as a single video.